# How to link to another tab with this jquery plugin (feature_list)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Take a look at this simple example 1rst : http://jqueryglobe.com/labs/feature_list/

In the bottom right corner, there is a box call "see project details". Basically, I'm trying to use this a a simple checkout form and I need to be able to fill one form and then, instead of that box at the bottom right, I would have a box saying "Go to STEP #2" and it would bring me to the 2nd item on the left.

I'm pretty sure it's trivial but Javascript is sorta alien to me :)

note: the .js file is : http://jqueryglobe.com/labs/feature_list/jquery.featureList-1.0.0.js

Can somebody help out? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can call the slide() function. The plugin hasn't been coded specifically with this in mind. You may be able to get the first slide by $('#mytabs').featureList.slide(-1); Basically the slides are numbered 0 to n and the slide function expects the index of the slide you are currently on.

On the example page it is in slide show mode. It starts at slide 1 (the middle slide). The slide function gets called with 1 and it moves to slide 2 (the last slide). It then gets called with slide(2) and moves to slide 0 since it is at the end.

Great find on this plugin. You may want to let the developer know about your needs and see if they can add the features.

It is also under the MIT license. I may start a fork over on my github account. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried 
    <a href="#" onclick="$(\'#tabs\').featureList.slide(1);">See project details</a>    but it didnt seem to work, am I forgetting something?